# In SQL, How do you choose which table to select from, based on a certain condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am in need of help in answering EXERCISE 74 from http://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref.

The database table used is:

- Classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement)

The question is:

- Get all ship classes of Russia. If there are no Russian ship classes in the database, display classes of all countries present in the DB.
  Result set: country, class.
- I know how to get all ship classes of Russia.
- I know how to get all ship classes of everything but Russia.

The way I could think to solve it would be to have a (TABLE A)select statement to get Russian classes, and then a (TABLE B)select statement to get non-russian classes and then choose which table to select from...

But I dont know the syntax to make it do the following: 
IF russia exists in (classes), select from (TABLE A) and if it doesn't, select from (TABLE B).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  You need to decide which database you are really using and tag appropriately.

Comment: @GordonLinoff okay doke.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out and was able to look at cleaner answers. The cleanest answer I found is as follows:

- SELECT country, class FROM Classes WHERE country='Russia'
- UNION
- SELECT country, class
- FROM classes
- WHERE 'Russia' NOT IN (SELECT country FROM classes)

The "WHERE 'Russia' NOT IN(SELECT country FROM classes)" is what I was looking for.